# Is there a way to use a package designed for Rstudio in R CLI?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

Someone wrote a package (we'll call it 'Thing') that relies heavily on Rstudio to work, including requiring the `rstudioapi` library.  It has an authentication routine that 
relies on the `rstudioapi::askForPassword("Enter your pw")` function.

If I run the setup routine, it throws this sort of error:

```
> setup_thing()
Thanks for downloading Thing, the custom R package for things.
Loading required package: rstudioapi
Error: RStudio not running
```

I am trying to avoid re-writing the entire library; Is there a way to install and set up the package in RStudio, but use its configured instance from R CLI?

Comment: I should note that I'm not a root user on the Rstudio Server -- merely a tenant.

Comment: Also, the reason we need to run from CLI is that we're using cron jobs to call Rscript and run the .R file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is unfortunately no. But there might be a work around. Have you investigated `cronR`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/README.html

You could potentially schedule the jobs within Rstudio itself.

Comment: It required me to add the packages shinyFiles and miniui, but other than that this worked great in my test case.  Thanks for the answer.